# Authenticating RestEnd Points with Okta and OAuth

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

We have a Java 8 backend application using SprintBoot with an embedded Jetty server.

The UI for the application is a thymeleaf UI.

Currently I have enabled authentication by integrating with Okta using the spring security SAML extension.

Now we have several REST endpoints in our backend and we would want them to be authenticated as well.

Upon reading, I started Okta OpenID Connect can be one choice which issues a JWT. However I am not clear on how to use this. How can I support both my SAML Authentication for Web UI and Authentication using OpenID Connect for my Rest Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If your client (Thymeleaf) is in your Spring Boot application, I'd suggest using Stormpath's Spring Boot Starter. This will give you authentication for your UI and security for your REST endpoints. The 2.0.0-rc1 release is [compatible with Okta](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/okta/OktaGettingStarted.md). In your `pom.xml`, you'll need the following XML:

```
<properties>
    <stormpath.version>2.0.0-okta-rc1</stormpath.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${stormpath.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am looking for something without stormpath.

Comment: The Stormpath SDK is an interim solution until we release more a more full-featured version of the Okta SDK for Java this summer. The Okta library is pretty low level: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java.

Comment: @MattRaible can you please point me to the full-featured version of the Okta SDK as you menthioned in the above comment. I am trying to achieve the same as in the original question by hemanthgk10. an example implementing both would be great.

Comment: The Okta Spring Boot Starter can be found at https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot. Note that it only works with Spring Boot 1.5.x and leverages OIDC, not SAML. If you're using Spring Boot 2, you can use its OAuth support: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot#add-authentication-with-okta